# Pygame - Zero Division Error: float division by zero

Tags: python, pygame

I went to Stack Overflow and read an algorithm that makes the enemy  follow after the player. It worked before, but now it's throwing a zero division error. I understand it's because python's dividing by 0 (meaning the distance between them is 0) however, I don't understand why it throws that error when before, it wasn't throwing it, even if the distance between the two was 0. Can anyone clarify?

```
import pygame
import math

pygame.init()
width, height = 800, 600
white = (255, 255, 255)

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((40, 50))
        self.image.fill(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = width / 2
        self.rect.y = height/ 2
        self.speed = 1


    def move_towards_another_object(self):
        self.dx = self.rect.x - player.rect.x
        self.dy = self.rect.y - player.rect.y
        self.dist = math.hypot(self.dx, self.dy)
        self.dx = self.dx/self.dist
        self.dy = self.dy/self.dist
        self.rect.x += self.dx * -self.speed
        self.rect.y += self.dy * -self.speed

enemy = Enemy()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 40))
        self.image.fill(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 0 + self.rect.x
        self.rect.y = height - self.rect.height

player = Player()

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(enemy, player)
gameExit = False

while not gameExit:
    enemy.move_towards_another_object()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Can you provide an error message? Have you tried using pdb? Do you have an older version from come version control system tool that you can cross examine it with?

Comment: With floats, there's always a chance for a tiny error, so even though you think `x` and `y` are the same number, they're actually one bit apart, so `x - y` is not actually 0 but 2e-308. And, while `dx / 0` is a `ZeroDivsionError`, `dx / 2e-308` is not (although the result is probably `float.inf`). So, that would explain why two nearly identical runs of the same code, one raises an exception while the other silently runs off to infinity.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Your posted code is not minimal, and depends on local files that (1) probably don't affect the problem, and (2) are not supplied, killing the execution.

Comment: @Prune I edited the code so that it is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

Your `enemy` sprite takes a unit step toward the `player` at each iteration.  Eventually, it's perfectly coincident with the player, and `self.dist` is a perfect 0.  Your coordinates are **integers**, so it's not hard to get the math to come out exactly.  In the previous version, were the coordinates floats?  That could easily explain the difference.

Comment: No they were not, but everytime dist = 0, the player respawned in a random location

Actually no I think I understood the difference. I was using the colliderect function, so dist never actually reached 0, hence why the game didn't crash

Comment: Right -- respawning in a random location would certainly reduce the chance of the distance dropping to zero: `player` would have to respawn on top of the `enemy`, a chance of 1 in 800 x 600.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with this piece of code:

```
def move_towards_another_object(self):
    self.dx = self.rect.x - player.rect.x
    self.dy = self.rect.y - player.rect.y
    self.dist = math.hypot(self.dx, self.dy)
    if self.dist == 0:
        self.rect.x = self.rect.x
        self.rect.y = self.rect.y
    else:
        self.dx = self.dx/self.dist
        self.dy = self.dy/self.dist
        self.rect.x += self.dx * -self.speed
        self.rect.y += self.dy * -self.speed
```